# ATMega328p wakes immediately after sleep

Tags: avr, atmega, atmel, atmega328p, sleep

I'm having issues with my current AVR-C project that runs on an ATMega328p. After issuing the sleep command the chip wakes up again immediately.
I want to wakeup with an external interrupt, but while trying to find the source of the issue I disabled them as well, expecting the IC to stay in power down forever.

```c
void system_sleep() {
    // adc disable
    ADCSRA = 0;

    wdt_disable();
    cli();

    // EICRA = _BV(ISC10) | _BV(ISC11);
    // EIMSK = _BV(INT1);
    EIMSK = 0;
    EICRA = 0;

    set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);

    sleep_bod_disable();
    sei();
    sleep_cpu();

    sleep_disable();

    // disable external interrupt
    EIMSK = 0;
    EICRA = 0;

    adc_init();
    wdt_enable(WDTO_1S);
}
```

Any ideas what could cause that? Is there an easy way to check what wakeup source triggered sleep to end?

Comment: Any interrupt will wake it. This is one function, we have no idea what other sources might also be enabled; the simplest assumption is that there are others. Trigger source is recorded by interrupt flags, and in turn CPU branching to the respective ISR if used.

Comment: For power down (according to the data sheet) only INT, PCINT and I²C, assuming I understand it right. I'm not using either of the latter two in the project. The only other interrupt vectors are a timer and the adc, which also both are disabled

Comment: When you do SEI, any active interrupt condition triggers on the next instruction. If you actually want it to sleep, you should clear the interrupt flag register before doing SEI

Comment: @david do you mean the external interrupt flag register `EIFR`? I gave that a go and it didn't help

Comment: I was just thinking generically of the SEI/Sleep sequence. What interrupts have you enabled? Maybe TXC bit (UART register)?

Comment: The only interrupts in use are Timer1_ovfl, ADC and then the INT1 I disabled for now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to the problem is not very exciting, as it was me simply overlooking something and for some reason didn't see it staring at the code for hours.
I was simply missing a call to `sleep_enable`. The following works completely as expected.

```c
cli();
sleep_enable();
sleep_bod_disable();
sei();

sleep_cpu();
sleep_disable();
```

Comment: Please put a green check mark in this answer, as it will be useful to others who have this kind of problem. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot about that